# MPI_Wait crashes simple program

Tags: c++, mpi

I wrote simple program with MPI and it crashes after calling `MPI_Wait`:

```
MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);

MPI_Request request;
double test = 0;
if (rank == 0) {
    MPI_Isend(&test, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, 1, 2, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &request);
} else {
    MPI_Irecv(&test, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, 2, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &request);
    MPI_Wait(&request, NULL);
}
```

I've overlooked the code may times, but can't understand why the program crashes.
I'm using Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: [What does your debugger tell you](http://i.stack.imgur.com/bXdkf.jpg)?

Comment: @flatmouse "test.exe has triggered a breakpoint". Stackstrace ends in unknown procedure in `Kernelbase.dll`.

Comment: Try passing `MPI_Status` as non-null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to use  MPI_STATUS_IGNORE rather than NULL. 
Disclaimer: I have never used this library.

https://www.mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-2.0/mpi-20-html/node47.htm

Comment: Thank you! It works! I was following that university tutorial, I'm very angry about it :) http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~cheung/Courses/561/Syllabus/92-MPI/async.html

Comment: @ArtemMostyaev, the tutorial author(s) had a different MPI implementation at hand. Open MPI defines `MPI_STATUS_IGNORE` to be a NULL pointer, so the code will work. MPICH-based MPI implementations define it to be a special non-zero constant value therefore the code fails. Passing `MPI_STATUS_IGNORE` is the only correct way to use `MPI_Wait` when you don't care about the status.